# /bin/sh - non interactive usage from Python

Tags: python, shell

I am invoking cmd from Python like this:

```
subpocess.Popen(['coffee'], shell=True)
```

which I belive is translated to:

```
/bin/sh -c "coffee"
```

From docs I have read that in non-interactive mode files like /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc are not read and default $PATH is used (init $PATH). Am I right? Is there the only way to add coffee to the $PATH is to copy it to /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the shell will inherit the `PATH` from the Python interpreter, i.e. it will be `os.getenv('PATH')`. Also, you can set the path within the command:

```
subprocess.Popen(['PATH=/where/ever/bin:$PATH coffee'], shell=True)
```

though I'd really advise you to either use the full path to `coffee`, or set the `PATH` before executing your Python program.

Comment: A better way to set environment variables for a command is with the `env` argument to `subprocess.Popen`. That works even if you don't involve the shell (which, after all, is usually a bad idea.)

Comment: @Thomas: yes, `env` would be even better, and maybe the OP shouldn't be using `shell=True` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I ended with installing coffee globally to /usr/local/bin since I dont want to hardcode PATH in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, none of the startup files are read for shells invoked as non-interactive commands, since presumably the environment is already set up.

Python, shells, and in fact almost everything will pass the existing environment or at least the `PATH` environment variable through to the child shell and so, in a way, you have already executed `.profile` or a bash extension. (Because it was run when the user logged in and other processes inherited the modified PATH.)

Options you have:

- specify a path for all system users in `/etc/profile`
- require appropriate PATH settings from the user (you inherit them)
- run subprocess utilities with full pathnames
- put all commands in directories already on the PATH

Comment: Thanks/upvoted. Accepted larsmans answer, because he has less reputation :)